# How to import Java file method to another Java file?

Tags: java, methods

I have two Java files, one called `Assign_2` and another called `ArrayMath`. I want to allow `ArrayMath`'s methods to be used in `Assign_2` like so:

```
ArrayMath.arrayAddition(a, b); //Called ArrayMath from Assign_2.java
```

What code allows `ArrayMath.java` methods to be used in `Assign_2.java`?

```
public class Assign_2 {

   /**
   * Main method to execute whole code.
   *
   * @param theArgs is used to keep consistency
   */

   public static void main(String[] theArgs) {
       Scanner input = null; // For file input
       PrintStream output = null; // For file output
       String inFileName = "in2a.txt"; //Input file and outputs
       String outFileName = "out.txt"; 
       boolean filesOk = false; // Checks for files to be accessed
       int[][] a = null; // Declaring the 4 arrays for operations
       int[][] b = null;
       int[][] c = null;  
       int[][] d = null;

       // Opens file for input and readys for output
       try {
         input = new Scanner(new File(inFileName));
         output = new PrintStream(new File(outFileName));
         filesOk = true;
         }
       catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("Can't open file - " + e);
         }
       if (filesOk) {
         a = get2DArray(input);
         b = get2DArray(input);
         c = get2DArray(input);
         d = get2DArray(input);
         // Sanity check for what is in the array and if right
         //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
         //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(b));
         //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(c));
         //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(d));

         // Calling to ArrayMath.java for operation results
         // Declaring arrays for final results
         int[][] sum = ArrayMath.arrayAddition(a, b);
         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(sum));
         //int[][] difference = ArrayMath.arraySubtraction(a, b);
         //int[][] multiplication = ArrayMath.arrayMultiply(a, b);
         }        
   }

   /**
   * get2DArray reads input file then creates 2D array
   * from the file.
   * 
   * @param input is a Scanner to input the file
   *
   * @return a 2D integer array filled with input values
   */

   public static int[][] get2DArray(Scanner theIn) {
      int rowSize = theIn.nextInt(); // Takes the first 2 numbers
      int colSize = theIn.nextInt(); // that provided column + row #'s
      int[][] a = new int[rowSize][colSize]; // New array with ^ #'s

      // For loops that add integers to arrays
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         for (int k = 0; k < a[i].length && theIn.hasNextInt(); k++) {
            a[i][k] = theIn.nextInt();
         }
      }
      return a; // Returns value to main method that was called from        
   }   
}
```

And ArrayMath.java is:

```
 public class ArrayMath {

   /**
   * Addition for 2D Arrays method
   * 
   * @param theA and theB are 2D arrays from Assign_2
   *
   * @return sum to Assign_2 main program
   */

   public static int[][] arrayAddition(int[][] theA, int[][] theB) {
      int[][] sum = new int[theA.length][theA.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < theA.length; i++) {
         for (int k = 0; k < theA[i].length; k++) {
            sum[i][k] = theA[i][k] + theB[i][k];
         }        
      }  
      return sum;  
  }   
}
```

Comment: Post the structure of your project.

Comment: Inheritance with 'extends' keyword ..?

Comment: Or make 'arrayAddition' static in ArrayMath class.

Comment: updated op with full code

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to define the method(s) in `ArrayMath` as `public` and `static`, e.g.:

```
public static void arrayAddition(int a, int b)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: This is not necessarily true, it can be non-static and still be used in another file. Making a method `static` really depends on the design.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I believe OP specifically stated that he wants to call it as `ArrayMath.arrayAddition(a, b);` which then would imply that the method is static unless OP disregards naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define the method in you want to import `ArrayMath.java` as `static`.
2. Assume the wrapper class is just called `ArrayMath`, make it a `public` method and then from `Assign_2` do `import ArrayMath`.
3. refer to the method like `ArrayMath.yourMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

Call the method after you create an object for `ArrayMath` class:

```
ArrayMath ob = new ArrayMath();
```

Then call the method in `Assign_2` class asfollowing

```
ob.arrayAddition(a, b);
```

Make sure the method is `public`.

Comment: There's no good answer for this question, we know nothing about OP's design.

Answer (score 0):

What all you have to do is to create an object from `ArrayMath` and use the method declared inside `Assign_2`

**E.g:**

```
ArrayMath obj = new ArrayMath();
obj.arrayAddition(a, b);
```

Read more about [creating objects in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways
1. inheritance `is-a` relationship
2. composition `has-a` relationship - but in case of `has-a` relationship you have to made `public` and `static` to your method to call from another class.